# Is there a way with Doctrine for the parent and the children to have the same parent constraint?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use Doctrine as the ORM with PostgreSQL. I have many entities, but here is my constraint :

A series has many seasons
A season has many episodes

I had a relation between episodes and series, to have a function series->getEpisodes() (without passing through season).

My question : **Is there a way to tell Doctrine that episode and season must have the same series ?** In another words, to add a constraint that say a child and his parent must have a common parent ?

Because without this constraint, it is theoretically possible for the episode (child) and the season (parent) to have a different series (but I avoid this with the application right now).

Comment: The relationship episode->tv show seems redundant, as long as you have episode->season->tv show you can query all the episodes for the tv show just fine. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vLsURbLiG3SUzvJ7N5hrk7/1

Comment: Yes it is redundant, but sometime I want to have the whole episodes from a serie. In this case, making a relation between the serie and the episodes is better than passing through the seasons.
I just want to make the constraint that the season and the episodes have the same relation. And I want to make this constraint in the doctrine config.

Comment: why is it "better"? in which way? I fail to see the benefit. you are only adding complexity and making your application more brittle. embrace the natural model for your application.

Comment: If you have this : serie->season->episode , if you want all of the episodes of a serie, you can't tell serie->getEpisodes(), you have to tell season->getEpisodes where season.serie = the serie I want. It's good because you use sql relations.

But if you make a direct relation between serie and episodes, you can get all faster (yes, it's ms).

Comment: You are confused about how this works, but you'll realize this in a few years I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own validation constraint. https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class HasSameSeason extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The episode\'s serie must match the season serie';


    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return static::class.'Validator';
    }
}
```

```
class HasSameSeasonValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof HasSameSeason) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, HasSameSeason::class);
        }

        if (!$value instanceof Episode) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, Episode::class);
        }

        if ($episode->getSerie() !== $episode->getSeason()->getSerie()) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I was looking to not doing this from the application, but more from the database side (with the doctrine config). But it seems to be impossible..